# Tobacco Plant Seeds

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-care, leaves, indoors

Hi my mum ordered some tobbaco seeds for me I was wondering if they will survive on my windowsill in uk temperature or will it need a hydroponic light? Or some way of getting more heat as they supposed to grow 20c. And if so does anyone know how to get the temperature to 20c?

Thanks!

Comment: Which tobacco plant?

Comment: Amber leaf seeds =)

Comment: Have you tried using a heat mat? You can get them in all kinds of sizes.

Comment: My mum won't allow the electricity bill lol thanks for the idea though written it down for the future